# MATLAB- Cell arrray numeric data splitting and extracting

Tags: arrays, matlab

My requirement is to create generate numerous complex matrices of 15x15 and  extract the diagonal elements and upper triangle elements as column vectors and finally combine them into  a single column vector.
As a part of the implementation I have done some code which looks similar to this
I have created a  program to generate 6 complex matrices using for loop and it is stored in a cell.
Code 1:-

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
N=15;
k=6;
C=cell(k,1)
for j = 1:k
    C{j}= rand(N,N) + 1i*rand(N,N); % Complex Matrix
end
```

Now the cell C 6 x1 contains  15x15 complex double numeric data in each cell array.
For extracting the diagonal elements extract the diagonal elements and upper triangle elements as column vectors and finally combine them into  a single column vector for a Matrix C I have the following code.

Code 2:-

```
D = diag(C)
L = triu(C,1)
U = tril(C,-1)
V= [D; real(U(:)); real(L(:))]
```

I would like to combine this Code2 approach for the Cell C obtained in Code1 by splitting the  each array in cell C- 6x1  with 15x15 in each cell into different arrays/ matrices of 15x15 order and then do the code2 operation.

Is it better to use Cell approach to create a loop of matrices or is there any other way to do. Please guide

Comment: Of course you can do this in a loop. Where is the problem?

Comment: Since all matrices have the same size, it's better to create a 3D array, where the matrices are stacked along the third dimension. Then extracting diagonals or triangular parts is easier

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the code2 operations is not allowed to do on a cell. I wanted to know is there work around for this

Comment: Reference the cell contents in the same way you do in "code 1": `D = diag(C{j})`.

Comment: Do note that `L = triu(C,1); L(:)` will give you 225 elements, more than half of them zeros. Instead you could do `L = C(triu(ones(size(C)),1)==1)`, which will give you only the elements above the diagonal.

Comment: @CrisLuengo.  Thanks a lot. I don't know why I missed out C{j} ! Also for removing zeroes I did like  this ... D = diag(A)
L = triu(A,1)
L = L(L~=0)
U = tril(A,-1)
U = U(U~=0)
[D; real(U); real(L)]...

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Sorry new to stack overflow, do not how to format code in comment

Comment: You can format code by putting it inside single backticks \`. Note that `L = L(L~=0)` will remove all zeros, so if `C` contains some zeros, those elements will not be in your output. The code I gave you returns all the elements above the diagonal, no matter what their value is.

Comment: Excuse my late reply . @CrisLuengo `L = C(triu(ones(size(C)),1)==1)` in this code, I used `C{j}` instead of `C ` the argument for the function ones() is not allowing cell type data. For just `C ` it does not work.